# Keras model with high accuracy but low val_acc

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I am using resnet50 transfer learning for the Oxford-IIIT Pet Dataset to classify 37 breeds of cats and dogs. The idea is to follow fastai implementation closely using Keras code. However, I managed to get a training accuracy as high as 90% but can't seem to increase my val_accuracy higher than a random guess (1/37 or ~ 3% val_acc).

Any idea how do Keras compute the validation acc and how can I improve it? Or is there something wrong with my preprocessing steps? Thanks a lot.

To get my validation steps, I use sklearn StratifiedShuffleSplit to get a balanced validation set.

```
# Create dataframe with labels and filenames
annotations = pd.read_csv("annotation/list.txt",header=None,delim_whitespace=True)

annotations.drop([1,2,3],axis=1, inplace=True)
annotations.columns = ["filenames"]

# Create label columns
trans = str.maketrans("_0123456789","           ")
annotations["labels"] = annotations["filenames"].str.translate(trans).str.strip()
annotations["filenames"] = annotations["filenames"] +".jpg"
```

```
# Creating a validation set
from sklearn.model_selection import StratifiedShuffleSplit

df_array = annotations.to_numpy(copy=True)

sss = StratifiedShuffleSplit(n_splits = 1, test_size=0.2)

valid_idx = [test for _,test in sss.split(df_array[:,0],df_array[:,1])]

validation = annotations.iloc[valid_idx[0]]
annotations.drop(valid_idx[0], inplace=True)
```

Then, constructing my generator and training my model.

```
from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

bs = 64

def normalize(x):
  imagenet_mean = np.array([0.485, 0.456, 0.406]).reshape(1,1,3)
  imagenet_sd = np.array([0.229, 0.224, 0.225]).reshape(1,1,3)
  return (x- imagenet_mean)/imagenet_sd



train_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1/255.,
                                  horizontal_flip = True,
                                  rotation_range=10,
                                  width_shift_range = 0.1,
                                  height_shift_range =0.1,
                                  brightness_range =(0.9,1.1),
                                  shear_range =0.1,
                                  preprocessing_function=normalize)

train_generator = train_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe=annotations,
                                                   directory =os.getcwd(),
                                                   x_col="filenames",
                                                   y_col="labels",
                                                   target_size = (224,224),
                                                   batch_size = bs,
                                                   )


val_datagen = ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1/255.,
                                preprocessing_function=normalize)

validation_generator = val_datagen.flow_from_dataframe(dataframe=validation,
                                                   directory =os.getcwd(),
                                                   x_col="filenames",
                                                   y_col="labels",
                                                   target_size = (224,224),
                                                   batch_size=bs,
                                                   )


from tensorflow.keras.applications.resnet50 import ResNet50
from tensorflow.keras import optimizers
from tensorflow.keras import Model
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Dense, GlobalAveragePooling2D, Flatten, BatchNormalization, Dropout


base_model = ResNet50(include_top=False,weights="imagenet")
x = base_model.output
x = GlobalAveragePooling2D()(x)
x = Flatten()(x)
x = BatchNormalization(epsilon=1e-05,momentum=0.1)(x)
x = Dropout(0.25)(x)
x = Dense(512,activation="relu")(x)
x = BatchNormalization(epsilon=1e-05,momentum=0.1)(x)
x = Dropout(0.5)(x)
predictions = Dense(37,activation="softmax")(x)

model = Model(inputs=base_model.input,outputs=predictions)

for layer in base_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = False

lr= 0.001
opti = optimizers.Adam(lr=lr, decay=lr/50)
model.compile(optimizer=opti,
             loss="categorical_crossentropy",
             metrics=["accuracy"])

model.fit_generator(train_generator,
                   epochs=10,
                   validation_data = validation_generator)

for layer in base_model.layers:
    layer.trainable = True

model.fit_generator(train_generator,
                   epochs=10,
                   validation_data = validation_generator)
```

```
By the 10 epochs before unfreezing my layers

loss = 0.2189
acc = 0.9255
val_loss = 5.5082
val_acc = 0.0401
```

Comment: You are not shuffling your data. What happens if you pass `shuffle=True` argument into `model.fit_generator`? If not, try passing `steps_per_epoch=len(train_generator) // bs` and `validation_steps=len(validation_generator) // bs` as well.

Comment: A high train accuracy and low validation accuracy is typically what overfitting looks like - have you done anything to check this isn't the case? This looks like a pretty big model, have you tried something much smaller? It would also help if we can see a model.summary() for this

Comment: If overfitting i assume my val_acc should increase before it decrease, but it havent move away from 3-4% since 1st epoch. I had to try the shuffle thing, thats my first thought but I thought the default setting for shuffle is True. I will update again

Comment: Shuffle and step_per_epoch not working. Any other suggestion?

Comment: @Beneblau,
Can you please provide the Annotations Data (if it is not confidential) so that we can try reproducing your issue and then work towards resolution. Thanks.

Comment: @TensorflowSupport Hi. the dataset can be found here. https://www.kaggle.com/tanlikesmath/the-oxfordiiit-pet-dataset

Comment: @Beneblau,
Sorry for the delayed response. I've downloaded the Dataset from Kaggle but couldn't find "Annotations" Data. I can try reproducing the issue at my end once I get that Data. Thanks!

Comment: @TensorflowSupport Hi. you can get the annotations data here:
http://www.robots.ox.ac.uk/~vgg/data/pets/
I have also added additional codes where I import my data. Thanks~